# Envío de ficheros AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html5, ajax

Estoy creando un formulario y además de llenar los datos necesito darle al usuario la opción de enviar un archivo PDF. Esto es opcional. El usuario bien puede decidir no adjuntar nada.

Hago el envío por Ajax serializando los datos y usando el objeto `FormData` para el archivo. Funciona perfecto excepto cuando el archivo esta vacío. Me tira error porque no reconoce el elemento.

**Código ajax**

```
$('#formalta').submit(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var formulario = $('#formalta');
     var datos = formulario.serialize();
     var archivos = new FormData();
     var url = 'funciones/alta.php';

      $.ajax({
              url: url + '?' + datos,
              type: 'POST',
              contentType: false,
              data: archivos,
              processData: false,
              success: function (data) {  Hace algo cuando funciona. }, 
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions,thrownError) {
                  alert(thrownError);}

        });//ajax-PDF
    });//submit
```

**Código PHP**

```
 $m=$db->lastInsertId();
  if($_FILES['pdfFile']['name']!= ''){
    if ($_FILES['pdfFile']['type']!="application/pdf."){
      $extension = strrchr($_FILES['pdfFile']['name'],'.' );
      $_FILES['pdfFile']['name']=$m.''.$extension;
      $serverPath='../../TTS/pages/calibration/files';
      $tempPath=$_FILES['pdfFile']['tmp_name'];
       $fileName= $_FILES['pdfFile']['name'];
       $format = $_FILES['pdfFile']['type'];
       $destiny=$serverPath.'/'.$fileName;
       $bdPath='files'.'/'.$fileName;
       $queryUpdate="UPDATE calibrationtbltemp SET pdf='$bdPath' where id=$m";
       $queryUpdateEx=$db->runQuery($queryUpdate) or die("no se ejecuto");
       if($queryUpdateEx){
                   $resultado = copy($_FILES["pdfFile"]["tmp_name"], $destiny);

         }//if queryUpdateEx

         }//if type is not application/pdf
      }  //empty
     echo $m;
```

El error que obtengo es:

> Notice: Undefined index: pdfFile in
>   C:\wamp\www\Calibration\funciones\alta.php on line 27

Comment: ¿qué error te aparece y cuál es el código de php que recibe el formulario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el error es `php` podrias hacer un isset para validar si enviaron o no el archivo:

```
if (isset($_POST['file']) {
  //procesar solo si existe el archivo
}
```

Comment: Estuve leyendo un poco y al parecer isset no funciona con Files. En su lugar se debe usar:  if($_FILES['pdfFile']['name']!= ''){}

Comment: aja, si tienes razón, la idea es esa que valides si existe o no el FILE en php. Espero que hayas resuelto tu problema

Comment: Si hago la validacion, pero sigue dando error. :c De igual manera, gracias :)

Comment: Tiene que salir, prueba  if(isset($_FILES)) {

Comment: Ya está, al final si funcionó con if(isset). Solo tenia que estructurarlo todo bien. Muchas gracias  :'D <3

Comment: @Yami Si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, considerá aceptarla haciendo click en el tilde a la izquierda.